# How to give a powerful kick in Foosball?

Tags: technique, foosball

I have played for one year and get quite frustrated this month. How to kick POWERFULLY?

Comment: It's all in the wrist.

Comment: How are you with a Frisbee?

Answer (score 3):

I had a tough time picking up the wrist flick initially. However, before I get to that, it's more important to learn control because that's how you'll be able to get the ball to where you want it and block it from your opponent(s). Once you have it where you want it, you'll be able to score far more often rather than if you simply shot powerfully with no control. Sure, speed looks great and all, but the better you get, the easier you will be able to score with the speed.

With regards to the wrist flick, you don't want to spin the players, but be light with your hand and, with a quick motion downwards while clasping the handle (think of rocketing your palm to the floor), tighten at the last moment. When you tense at the last moment after going very quickly, you will generate more power.

I hope I explained things clearly. It's a little hard to explain with no pictures or videos. Just keep practicing and you will get better.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

One technique I use to create power is to have the foosball player start by pinning the ball between him and the table in a forward position (in front of the player).  The idea here is to achieve an almost full rotation of the player and then hit the ball. It is almost 360 degree spin and creates amazing power.  This is achieved by placing your wrist on the handle then, in a quick motion, pulling up and rolling the handle through the 360 degrees. At the end of the pull up your fingers cup and steady the handle (to avoid the out of control spin).  It can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qmr3i7ZqwZc) in slow motion. Especially at the 2:10 mark.